# Given the generating function for the sequence $a_n$, can we find the generating function for $a_na_{n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

Given $f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n$, can we find a function $g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_na_{n+1}x^n$?

When we solve the recurrences of the form $a_na_{n+1} = h(n)$, it is normal to define $b_n = (-1)^n \ln (a_n)$ as it turns our equation in something like $b_{n+1} - b_n = H(n)$, so I wonder what would be the generating function of $g(x) = \ln (f(x))$... I'm not even sure we can center it at origin tho, any ideas?

Here is one try:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n, g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} b_nx^n \implies$$

$$f(x)\cdot g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} c_n x^n$$ with $$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n b_ka_{n-k}$$

So, if we can find $b_n$ such that

$$a_na_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k a_{n-k}$$

we can solve the problem with simply Cauchy's product. But how do we invert such a sum? The difference operator doesn't apply directly. The Cauchy product may be the way to find the series of $h(x) = \exp (f(x))$ but that takes a lot of calculations.

EDIT:  Oleksandr Kulkov gave us a nice insight.

If $$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n = a_0 + x \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+1}x^n$$

So $$\frac{f(x)-a_0}x = g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+1}x^n$$

I want this:

$$\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(\sqrt x e^{it})g(\sqrt x e^{-it}) dt$$

Comment: If $a_0=1$ the formula for the logarithm is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Logarithms_of_an_OGF)

Comment: @Marco oh thanks, but is kind of distant of what I want yet. I feel like I would need to understand better the arithmetic of formal series

Comment: More appropriate link is probably [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Hadamard_products_and_diagonal_generating_functions), as $g(x) = (f \odot xf)(x)$. It's unlikely that there is a simpler formula, unless $f(x)$ is of a certain simpler form (e.g. it's possible to better describe the result when $f(x)$ is rational, and it would still be rational).